# How do I skip emails that do not contain any data tables in the body?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

Currently, I'm using VBA code to extract new hire emails from a sub inbox looking back 45 days. The emails contain data tables that I extract, so I can copy the columns. I want to avoid opening all 45 days worth of emails to copy data. Sometimes we get emails with no data table, just a sentence that reads 'no records found' which means we didn't hire or terminate anyone.

Issue: When we receive emails with no data tables, the order of dates of the emails are thrown off.

If on 6/2, 6/3, and 6/4 I get an email with data tables, and on 6/5 I get a email with no data tables, but on 6/6 (today's date) I get an email that does have data, the audit will not skip the receivedTime of 6/5 and it adds the data from 6/6 instead. When I do the audit, it displays 6/2, 6/3, 6/4, and 6/5 (with the data table from 6/6) instead of 6/2, 6/3, 6/4, and 6/6 (skipping 6/5).

```vb
Sub Extractor()

Range("A2:H30000").Clear
Dim OLApp As Outlook.Application
Set OLApp = New Outlook.Application

Dim ONS As Outlook.Namespace

Set ONS = OLApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Dim MYFOLDER As Outlook.Folder
 
Set MYFOLDER = ONS.Folders("fakeemail@fakeemail.com").Folders("Inbox")
Set MYFOLDER = MYFOLDER.Folders("NewHires")

Dim OLMAIL As Outlook.MailItem
Set OLMAIL = OLApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

Set myItems = MYFOLDER.Items
myItems.Sort "ReceivedTime", True
 
For Each OLMAIL In myItems
    Dim daysBack As Date
    Dim dateOfEmail As Date
    daysBack = VBA.Now - 45
    dateOfEmail = OLMAIL.ReceivedTime
    If dateOfEmail < daysBack Then Exit For

    Dim oHTML As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Set oHTML = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

    Dim oElColl As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    With oHTML
        .Body.innerHTML = OLMAIL.HTMLBody
        Set oElColl = .getElementsByTagName("table")
    End With
 
    Dim t As Long, r As Long, c As Long
    Dim eRow As Long

    For t = 0 To oElColl.Length - 1
        eRow = Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
        For r = 0 To (oElColl(t).Rows.Length - 1)
            For c = 0 To (oElColl(t).Rows(r).Cells.Length - 1)
                Range("A" & eRow).Offset(r, c).Value = oElColl(t).Rows(r).Cells(c).innerText
            Next c
        Next r
        eRow = Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    
    Next t

    Cells(eRow, 1) = "Sender's Name:" & " " & OLMAIL.Sender
    Cells(eRow, 1).Interior.Color = vbRed
    Cells(eRow, 1).Font.Color = vbWhite
    Cells(eRow, 2) = OLMAIL.ReceivedTime
    Cells(eRow, 2).Interior.Color = vbBlue
    Cells(eRow, 2).Font.Color = vbWhite
    Range(Cells(eRow, 1), Cells(eRow, 2)).Columns.AutoFit
Next OLMAIL

Range("A2").Select

Set OLApp = Nothing
Set OLMAIL = Nothing
Set oHTML = Nothing
Set oElColl = Nothing

ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBE.MainWindow.Visible = False
 
End Sub
```

Comment: You can add a check that `oElColl.Length >0` and not write anything to the sheet unless that passes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested, but something like this should work.  Some parts split out into separate methods to keep the main logic clear.

```vb
Sub Extractor()

    Const DAYS_BACK As Long = 45
    
    Dim OLApp As Outlook.Application, ONS As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim OLMAIL As Outlook.MailItem, MYFOLDER As Outlook.Folder
    Dim oHTML As MSHTML.HTMLDocument, oElColl As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim cDest As Range, tbl As Object, myItems As Object, ws As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet        'or some specific named sheet
    ws.Range("A2:H30000").Clear
    Set cDest = ws.Range("A2")  'start point for copied data
    
    Set OLApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set ONS = OLApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set MYFOLDER = ONS.Folders("fakeemail@fakeemail.com"). _
                   Folders("Inbox").Folders("NewHires")
    
    Set myItems = MYFOLDER.Items
    myItems.Sort "ReceivedTime", True
    
    For Each OLMAIL In myItems
        If OLMAIL.ReceivedTime > (VBA.Now - DAYS_BACK) Then 'within the time window?
            
            Set oHTML = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
            With oHTML
                .Body.innerHTML = OLMAIL.HTMLBody
                Set oElColl = .getElementsByTagName("table")
            End With
            
            If oElColl.Length > 0 Then       'any tables to process?
                AddHeader cDest, OLMAIL      'add header for this mail
                For Each tbl In oElColl
                    TableToRange cDest, tbl  'transfer table content
                Next tbl
            End If
        End If
    Next OLMAIL
    ws.Range("A1:B1").EntireColumn.AutoFit
End Sub

'copy an HTML table to a worksheet, starting at cell `cDest`
Sub TableToRange(cDest As Range, tbl As Object)
    Dim r As Long, c As Long, rw As Object
    For r = 0 To tbl.Rows.Length - 1
        Set rw = tbl.Rows(r)
        For c = 0 To rw.Cells.Length - 1
            cDest.Offset(0, c).Value = rw.Cells(c).innerText
        Next c
        Set cDest = cDest.Offset(1, 0) 'next sheet row
    Next r
End Sub

'add header info and move destination row down
Sub AddHeader(cDest As Range, oMail As Object)
    With cDest
        .Value = "Sender's Name:" & " " & oMail.Sender
        .Interior.Color = vbRed
        .Font.Color = vbWhite
        .Offset(0, 1).Value = oMail.ReceivedTime
        .Offset(0, 1).Interior.Color = vbBlue
        .Offset(0, 1).Font.Color = vbWhite
    End With
    Set cDest = cDest.Offset(1, 0) 'next sheet row
End Sub
```

Comment: I am getting this error "unsupport object or method"  @ cDest.Offset(0, c).Value = rw.Cells(c).Value any idea? I am trying to figure it out myself as well/

Comment: Typo - `.Value` should have been `.innerText`